# Get only a few properties from httprequest with newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json.net, resteasy

I need to parse such response from google:

https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore?hl=en-US&tz=-180&req=%7B%22comparisonItem%22:%5B%7B%22keyword%22:%22react%22,%22geo%22:%22%22,%22time%22:%22today+12-m%22%7D%5D,%22category%22:0,%22property%22:%22%22%7D&tz=-180

Response looks smth like this

```
other properties: ...
widgets: [{token: ""},...]
```

For sending requests I'm using RestEase. RestEase response from Google I'd like to map to my model

```
public class TokenResult
{
    [JsonProperty("widgets[0].token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting an error when restease is trying to parse response.
So how can got only a token from the very first widget?

Comment: I suggest you start by looking at your question yourself. How is the question presented to you? Now, think how the question appears to us... You might want to think about how you can significantly cut the "noise" in your question, in other words, how you could reduce the amount of "stuff" that's not directly related to your question/problem to make the question/problem readable and understandable...

Comment: Now you eliminated "everything" from your question. I suggested to cut noise, and remove stuff from your question that is not related to your problem. I did not suggest to eliminate almost everything. Without knowing the Json data layout, we wouldn't know where in your Json data the "first widget" would be located. The part of the Json data layout pertaining to the first widget (including the hierarchy from the root object down to the first widget object) needs to be in your question. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) But anything else, any other data, stuff, whatever in in the Json data layout being of no interest, stuff that does not inform us about the Json data layout in relation to how to get from the root Json object to the "first widget" should be cut away. That's what i was trying to suggest... ;-)

Comment: @Pyrejkee Here you go: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bGL8aZ

Comment: @RahulSharma, do I really need create so much entities as from google response? I just want to extract one field and for that I have create a lot of huge classes

Comment: @Pyrejkee Well the ideal way would be to parse this JSON string into its respective components and get your required data but if you only want a particular piece of information, you can use a `Regex` solution: https://regex101.com/r/pFj20B/1. You token matches are in Group 1.

Comment: @RahulSharms, yes, regex would be nice there, but I'm using RestEase which uses newton.json under the hood, so I'm not able to use regex. Moreover approach you've provided me earlier doesn't work correctly since google sends in response strange banch of symbols in the very beginning >)]}'<

Comment: @Pyrejkee Yes I know that. You would have to handle that separately at your end to avoid those extra characters and get the JSON string from the text file.

Comment: @RahulSharma, so if I understood correctly there is no way to avoid creating so much classes to get just token?

Comment: @Pyrejkee You can create your own model classes also to parse your JSON string. I prefer using the json2csharp tool: http://json2csharp.com/ to create c# model classes for you based on your JSON string. For validating your JSON string you can use https://jsonlint.com/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a discussion on the requirement of your problem, you can use `dynamic` to get your `token` from the JSON string without using a model class. A working demo is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bGL8aZ

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json=@"{'widgets':[{'request':{'time':'2018-07-09 2019-07-09','resolution':'WEEK','locale':'en-US','comparisonItem':[{'geo':{},'complexKeywordsRestriction':{'keyword':[{'type':'BROAD','value':'react'}]}}],'requestOptions':{'property':'','backend':'IZG','category':0}},'lineAnnotationText':'Search interest','bullets':[{'text':'react'}],'showLegend':false,'showAverages':false,'helpDialog':{'title':'Interest over time','content':'Numbers represent search interest relative to the highest point on the chart for the given region and time. A value of 100 is the peak popularity for the term. A value of 50 means that the term is half as popular. A score of 0 means there was not enough data for this term.'},'token':'APP6_UEAAAAAXSXKDwW-kwcTrkXhBuCj17xOewtWmROU','id':'TIMESERIES','type':'fe_line_chart','title':'Interest over time','template':'fe','embedTemplate':'fe_embed','version':'1','isLong':true,'isCurated':false},{'request':{'geo':{},'comparisonItem':[{'time':'2018-07-09 2019-07-09','complexKeywordsRestriction':{'keyword':[{'type':'BROAD','value':'react'}]}}],'resolution':'COUNTRY','locale':'en-US','requestOptions':{'property':'','backend':'IZG','category':0}},'geo':'world','resolution':'countries','searchInterestLabel':'Search interest','displayMode':'regions','helpDialog':{'title':'Interest by region','content':'See in which location your term was most popular during the specified time frame. Values are calculated on a scale from 0 to 100, where 100 is the location with the most popularity as a fraction of total searches in that location, a value of 50 indicates a location which is half as popular. A value of 0 indicates a location where there was not enough data for this term. \u003cp\u003e\u003cp\u003e \u003cb\u003eNote:\u003c/b\u003e A higher value means a higher proportion of all queries, not a higher absolute query count. So a tiny country where 80% of the queries are for \'bananas\' will get twice the score of a giant country where only 40% of the queries are for \'bananas\'.','url':'https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4355212'},'color':'PALETTE_COLOR_1','index':0,'bullet':'react','token':'APP6_UEAAAAAXSXKD-rIwyhC21Abw8P2nPfb7AGhxrZ1','id':'GEO_MAP','type':'fe_geo_chart_explore','title':'Interest by region','template':'fe','embedTemplate':'fe_embed','version':'1','isLong':true,'isCurated':false},{'request':{'restriction':{'geo':{},'time':'2018-07-09 2019-07-09','originalTimeRangeForExploreUrl':'today 12-m','complexKeywordsRestriction':{'keyword':[{'type':'BROAD','value':'react'}]}},'keywordType':'ENTITY','metric':['TOP','RISING'],'trendinessSettings':{'compareTime':'2017-07-08 2018-07-08'},'requestOptions':{'property':'','backend':'IZG','category':0},'language':'en'},'helpDialog':{'title':'Related topics','content':'Users searching for your term also searched for these topics. You can view by the following metrics: \u003cp\u003e* \u003cb\u003eTop\u003c/b\u003e - The most popular topics. Scoring is on a relative scale where a value of 100 is the most commonly searched topic and a value of 50 is a topic searched half as often as the most popular term, and so on. \u003cp\u003e* \u003cb\u003eRising\u003c/b\u003e - Related topics with the biggest increase in search frequency since the last time period. Results marked \'Breakout\' had a tremendous increase, probably because these topics are new and had few (if any) prior searches.'},'color':'PALETTE_COLOR_1','keywordName':'react','token':'APP6_UEAAAAAXSXKD9wlRrdtpbUyYXxko216LXZt21ra','id':'RELATED_TOPICS','type':'fe_related_searches','title':'Related topics','template':'fe','embedTemplate':'fe_embed','version':'1','isLong':false,'isCurated':false},{'request':{'restriction':{'geo':{},'time':'2018-07-09 2019-07-09','originalTimeRangeForExploreUrl':'today 12-m','complexKeywordsRestriction':{'keyword':[{'type':'BROAD','value':'react'}]}},'keywordType':'QUERY','metric':['TOP','RISING'],'trendinessSettings':{'compareTime':'2017-07-08 2018-07-08'},'requestOptions':{'property':'','backend':'IZG','category':0},'language':'en'},'helpDialog':{'title':'Related queries','content':'Users searching for your term also searched for these queries. You can sort by the following metrics: \u003cp\u003e* \u003cb\u003eTop\u003c/b\u003e - The most popular search queries. Scoring is on a relative scale where a value of 100 is the most commonly searched query, 50 is a query searched half as often as the most popular query, and so on. \u003cp\u003e* \u003cb\u003eRising\u003c/b\u003e - Queries with the biggest increase in search frequency since the last time period. Results marked \'Breakout\' had a tremendous increase, probably because these queries are new and had few (if any) prior searches.','url':'https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4355000'},'color':'PALETTE_COLOR_1','keywordName':'react','token':'APP6_UEAAAAAXSXKD10s1DrnqESw00VH8rfqAEq4ZjmA','id':'RELATED_QUERIES','type':'fe_related_searches','title':'Related queries','template':'fe','embedTemplate':'fe_embed','version':'1','isLong':false,'isCurated':false}],'keywords':[{'keyword':'react','name':'react','type':'Search term'}],'timeRanges':['Past 12 months'],'examples':[],'shareText':'Explore search interest for react by time, location and popularity on Google Trends','shouldShowMultiHeatMapMessage':false}";

        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        foreach(var result in data.widgets)
        {    
            Console.WriteLine(result.token);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
APP6_UEAAAAAXSXKDwW-kwcTrkXhBuCj17xOewtWmROU
APP6_UEAAAAAXSXKD-rIwyhC21Abw8P2nPfb7AGhxrZ1
APP6_UEAAAAAXSXKD9wlRrdtpbUyYXxko216LXZt21ra
APP6_UEAAAAAXSXKD10s1DrnqESw00VH8rfqAEq4ZjmA
```

You would need to take care of the extra characters that are before the actual JSON string in the text file in order for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `.SelectTokens(path)`:

```
var json = "{\n\t\"widgets\": [{\n\t\t\t\"request\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"time\": \"2018-07-10 2019-07-10\",\n\t\t\t\t\"resolution\": \"WEEK\",\n\t\t\t\t\"locale\": \"en-US\",\n\t\t\t\t\"comparisonItem\": [{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"geo\": {},\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"complexKeywordsRestriction\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"keyword\": [{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"type\": \"BROAD\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"react\"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t]\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t\t\"requestOptions\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"property\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"backend\": \"IZG\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"category\": 0\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"lineAnnotationText\": \"Search interest\",\n\t\t\t\"bullets\": [{\n\t\t\t\t\t\"text\": \"react\"\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t\"showLegend\": false,\n\t\t\t\"showAverages\": false,\n\t\t\t\"helpDialog\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"title\": \"Interest over time\",\n\t\t\t\t\"content\": \"Numbers represent search interest relative to the highest point on the chart for the given region and time. A value of 100 is the peak popularity for the term. A value of 50 means that the term is half as popular. A score of 0 means there was not enough data for this term.\"\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"token\": \"APP6_UEAAAAAXSbu2jqA25pSUFsKBYxQA0kFsKdcLCgU\",\n\t\t\t\"id\": \"TIMESERIES\",\n\t\t\t\"type\": \"fe_line_chart\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"Interest over time\",\n\t\t\t\"template\": \"fe\",\n\t\t\t\"embedTemplate\": \"fe_embed\",\n\t\t\t\"version\": \"1\",\n\t\t\t\"isLong\": true,\n\t\t\t\"isCurated\": false\n\t\t}, {\n\t\t\t\"request\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"geo\": {},\n\t\t\t\t\"comparisonItem\": [{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"time\": \"2018-07-10 2019-07-10\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"complexKeywordsRestriction\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"keyword\": [{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"type\": \"BROAD\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"react\"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t]\n\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t\t\"resolution\": \"COUNTRY\",\n\t\t\t\t\"locale\": \"en-US\",\n\t\t\t\t\"requestOptions\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"property\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"backend\": \"IZG\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"category\": 0\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"geo\": \"world\",\n\t\t\t\"resolution\": \"countries\",\n\t\t\t\"searchInterestLabel\": \"Search interest\",\n\t\t\t\"displayMode\": \"regions\",\n\t\t\t\"helpDialog\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"title\": \"Interest by region\",\n\t\t\t\t\"content\": \"See in which location your term was most popular during the specified time frame. Values are calculated on a scale from 0 to 100, where 100 is the location with the most popularity as a fraction of total searches in that location, a value of 50 indicates a location which is half as popular. A value of 0 indicates a location where there was not enough data for this term. \\u003cp\\u003e\\u003cp\\u003e \\u003cb\\u003eNote:\\u003c/b\\u003e A higher value means a higher proportion of all queries, not a higher absolute query count. So a tiny country where 80% of the queries are for \\\"bananas\\\" will get twice the score of a giant country where only 40% of the queries are for \\\"bananas\\\".\",\n\t\t\t\t\"url\": \"https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4355212\"\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"color\": \"PALETTE_COLOR_1\",\n\t\t\t\"index\": 0,\n\t\t\t\"bullet\": \"react\",\n\t\t\t\"token\": \"APP6_UEAAAAAXSbu2q_7M5NSV_6S_n66X17hnN3geL_X\",\n\t\t\t\"id\": \"GEO_MAP\",\n\t\t\t\"type\": \"fe_geo_chart_explore\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"Interest by region\",\n\t\t\t\"template\": \"fe\",\n\t\t\t\"embedTemplate\": \"fe_embed\",\n\t\t\t\"version\": \"1\",\n\t\t\t\"isLong\": true,\n\t\t\t\"isCurated\": false\n\t\t}, {\n\t\t\t\"request\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"restriction\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"geo\": {},\n\t\t\t\t\t\"time\": \"2018-07-10 2019-07-10\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"originalTimeRangeForExploreUrl\": \"today 12-m\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"complexKeywordsRestriction\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"keyword\": [{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"type\": \"BROAD\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"react\"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t]\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\"keywordType\": \"ENTITY\",\n\t\t\t\t\"metric\": [\"TOP\", \"RISING\"],\n\t\t\t\t\"trendinessSettings\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"compareTime\": \"2017-07-09 2018-07-09\"\n\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\"requestOptions\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"property\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"backend\": \"IZG\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"category\": 0\n\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\"language\": \"en\"\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"helpDialog\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"title\": \"Related topics\",\n\t\t\t\t\"content\": \"Users searching for your term also searched for these topics. You can view by the following metrics: \\u003cp\\u003e* \\u003cb\\u003eTop\\u003c/b\\u003e - The most popular topics. Scoring is on a relative scale where a value of 100 is the most commonly searched topic and a value of 50 is a topic searched half as often as the most popular term, and so on. \\u003cp\\u003e* \\u003cb\\u003eRising\\u003c/b\\u003e - Related topics with the biggest increase in search frequency since the last time period. Results marked \\\"Breakout\\\" had a tremendous increase, probably because these topics are new and had few (if any) prior searches.\"\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"color\": \"PALETTE_COLOR_1\",\n\t\t\t\"keywordName\": \"react\",\n\t\t\t\"token\": \"APP6_UEAAAAAXSbu2j6t0UwOOyihkflYRxWkIyxgSgNY\",\n\t\t\t\"id\": \"RELATED_TOPICS\",\n\t\t\t\"type\": \"fe_related_searches\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"Related topics\",\n\t\t\t\"template\": \"fe\",\n\t\t\t\"embedTemplate\": \"fe_embed\",\n\t\t\t\"version\": \"1\",\n\t\t\t\"isLong\": false,\n\t\t\t\"isCurated\": false\n\t\t}, {\n\t\t\t\"request\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"restriction\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"geo\": {},\n\t\t\t\t\t\"time\": \"2018-07-10 2019-07-10\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"originalTimeRangeForExploreUrl\": \"today 12-m\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"complexKeywordsRestriction\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"keyword\": [{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"type\": \"BROAD\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\"value\": \"react\"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t]\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\"keywordType\": \"QUERY\",\n\t\t\t\t\"metric\": [\"TOP\", \"RISING\"],\n\t\t\t\t\"trendinessSettings\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"compareTime\": \"2017-07-09 2018-07-09\"\n\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\"requestOptions\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"property\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"backend\": \"IZG\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"category\": 0\n\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\"language\": \"en\"\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"helpDialog\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"title\": \"Related queries\",\n\t\t\t\t\"content\": \"Users searching for your term also searched for these queries. You can sort by the following metrics: \\u003cp\\u003e* \\u003cb\\u003eTop\\u003c/b\\u003e - The most popular search queries. Scoring is on a relative scale where a value of 100 is the most commonly searched query, 50 is a query searched half as often as the most popular query, and so on. \\u003cp\\u003e* \\u003cb\\u003eRising\\u003c/b\\u003e - Queries with the biggest increase in search frequency since the last time period. Results marked \\\"Breakout\\\" had a tremendous increase, probably because these queries are new and had few (if any) prior searches.\",\n\t\t\t\t\"url\": \"https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4355000\"\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"color\": \"PALETTE_COLOR_1\",\n\t\t\t\"keywordName\": \"react\",\n\t\t\t\"token\": \"APP6_UEAAAAAXSbu2mSFz-N3e9aT0TUMZbJ-YOtU2Qjp\",\n\t\t\t\"id\": \"RELATED_QUERIES\",\n\t\t\t\"type\": \"fe_related_searches\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"Related queries\",\n\t\t\t\"template\": \"fe\",\n\t\t\t\"embedTemplate\": \"fe_embed\",\n\t\t\t\"version\": \"1\",\n\t\t\t\"isLong\": false,\n\t\t\t\"isCurated\": false\n\t\t}\n\t],\n\t\"keywords\": [{\n\t\t\t\"keyword\": \"react\",\n\t\t\t\"name\": \"react\",\n\t\t\t\"type\": \"Search term\"\n\t\t}\n\t],\n\t\"timeRanges\": [\"Past 12 months\"],\n\t\"examples\": [],\n\t\"shareText\": \"Explore search interest for react by time, location and popularity on Google Trends\",\n\t\"shouldShowMultiHeatMapMessage\": false\n}\n";

var obj = JToken.Parse(json);

var tokens = obj.SelectTokens("widgets[*].token");
```